# How to update time dynamically in flutter

Tags: flutter, setstate, flutter-getx

I have a list view with list tiles with each containing a region with its specific time.
I am using a Getx controller with the class WorldTime with two parameters location and time.
There is already a timer that's called during setState to update the clock widget, but how do I implement this to update each list tile time or is there any other way to update the time automatically without calling setState.

```
class _WorldClockState extends State<WorldClock> {
final WorldTimeController worldTimeController =
      Get.put(WorldTimeController());
  String formattedTime = DateFormat('h:mm').format(DateTime.now());
  String hour = DateFormat('a').format(DateTime.now());
  late Timer _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer =
        Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), (timer) => _update());
  }

  void _update() {
    setState(() {
      formattedTime = DateFormat('h:mm').format(DateTime.now());
      hour = DateFormat('a').format(DateTime.now());
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(formattedTime,
                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                            fontSize: 80.0,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            letterSpacing: 5.0)),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 5.0),
                      child: Text(
                        hour,
                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontSize: 30.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  DateFormat('EE,  MMM d').format(DateTime.now()),
                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    letterSpacing: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                child: Divider(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  height: 2.0,
                ),
              ),
              GetBuilder<WorldTimeController>(
                id: 'Clockid',
                builder: (value) => Container(
                  height: 600.0,
                  width: 450.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: worldTimeController.WorldTimeList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 18.0),
                        child: Slidable(
                          key: UniqueKey(),
                          startActionPane: ActionPane(
                            motion: ScrollMotion(),
                            dismissible: DismissiblePane(onDismissed: () {
                              worldTimeController.WorldTimeList.removeAt(index);
                            }),
                            children: const [],
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Text(
                                worldTimeController
                                    .WorldTimeList[index].location,
                                style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                    color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 25)),
                            trailing: Text(
                              '${value.getTime(worldTimeController.WorldTimeList[index].location)}',
                              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                  color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 35.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 192.0, bottom: 20.0),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Get.to(() => const RegionSelectScreen());
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.public),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

controller:

```
class WorldTimeController extends GetxController {
var WorldTimeList = <WorldTime>[].obs;
  var newUrl;
  var newResponse;

  Future<dynamic> getTime(location) async {
    newUrl = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/${location}";
    newResponse = await get(Uri.parse(newUrl));
    Map newData = jsonDecode(newResponse.body);
    var time = newData['datetime'];
    String dateTime = newData["utc_datetime"];
    String offset = newData["utc_offset"];
    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(dateTime);
    now = now.add(Duration(
        hours: int.parse(offset.substring(1, 3)),
        minutes: int.parse(offset.substring(4))));
    update(['Clockid']);
    return time = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    List? storedWorldTime = GetStorage().read<List>('WorldTime');
if (storedWorldTime != null) {
  WorldTimeList.assignAll(
      storedWorldTime.map((e) => WorldTime.fromJson(e)).toList());
}
ever(WorldTimeList, (_) {
  GetStorage().write('WorldTime', WorldTimeList.toList());
});
super.onInit();
}
}
```

Comment: BTW. The DateTime instance got an hour, Minute, month etc. getter for grabbing the values. You don’t need to format it

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to reduce the fontSize of `AM` and `PM`, that's why I formatted it

Answer (score 0):

In your getXcontroller class you can create  function to update the hours and on this function you can add

> **update(['clockId']);**

then in your screen

```
return GetBuilder<WorldTimeController>(
        id: 'clockId',
        init: WorldTimeController(), // If is init this line is not necessary
        builder: (worldTimeController) => Container(
                height: 600.0,
                width: 450.0,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: worldTimeController.WorldTimeList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) => Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 18.0),
                              child: Slidable(
                                key: UniqueKey(),
                                startActionPane: ActionPane(
                                  motion: ScrollMotion(),
                                  dismissible: DismissiblePane(onDismissed: () {
                                    worldTimeController.WorldTimeList.removeAt(
                                        index);
                                  }),
                                  children: [],
                                ),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  leading: Text(
                                      '${worldTimeController.WorldTimeList[index].location}',
                                      style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                          color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 25)),
                                  trailing: Text(
                                    "${worldTimeController.WorldTimeList[index].time}",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                        color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 35.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )),
                  ),
                ),
            
            );
```

Then even that change something in your function this will refresh all the list inside your *clockId*.

Try to avoid setState because this method rebuild all the view and when your app grows does't has good performance

Here an example:

> https://github.com/alcampospalacios/GetX_UpdateAll_Example

Comment: Thanks, this way is better but how can I update the time for all the items in the list view

Comment: Bro when you use update(['idClock']) function in controller, everything in the view with idClock is updated, this method work something like provider state managemnt. Better i going to do a example

Comment: I edit my answer with a repo in github where i show you how do it.

Comment: I can't seem to solve my problem, I have update my answer, can you check whats wrong with my code

Comment: First if your are using *ids* you don't need declare WorldTimeList like observable, second you are using **Update([Clockid])** inside your **getTime** function but your getTime is called directly (Not recommend it) in your screen, so when you call *update* the value of your function yet has not return the value them there is nothing new to update.

Comment: Update: the function works, but in the list tile it shows `Instance of Future<dynamic>`